# tableタグの列をソートするプラグインはないでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, jquery

お世話になります。

以下のようなプラグインを探しているのですが
配布サイトがダウンしていたり、マニュアル整備がないため
苦心しています。

・jQueryのプラグイン
・テーブルに適用する
・ヘッダをクリックすると縦方向に、セルの値でソート
・画像が入った列が１列あるので、その場合は画像のファイル名か属性などでソート
・ソートさえできれば、編集などの機能は不要です。

ありそうでない、という類のプラグインなのでしょうか？
もしご存知の方がいれば、情報をいただけないでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

「jquery table sort」 で検索すると一番上に出てきましたが、お試しになったでしょうか？

[jQuery plugin: Tablesorter 2.0](http://tablesorter.com/docs/)

画像の列については、span.hide などで見えないテキストを書き込んでおくことで、ソート可能になるかと思います。

既にお試しのものがあれば、それは〇〇の理由でダメだった、など、追記されると、宜しいかと思います。

Comment: お返事ありがとうございます。

jquery table sortと、まさにそのキーワードで検索していて
Tablesorterおよびその解説サイトが先頭にきていたのですが
ちょうど私が調査していた日に公式がダウンしていたのか
繋がらなくて、てっきりメンテナンスが終了したプラグインだと思っていました。

私が試したいくつかのプラグインでは、
<td><span style="display:none">ooo</span><img src=""></td>
といった書き方をしてもソート自体が行われなかったと記憶しています。
これらは直接tdの中身をみているんでしょうね。

恐れ入りますが、試したプラグイン、理由などは後ほど追記させていただきます。